# Building a binary tree from a recursively defined string notation

Tags: string, parsing, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I've been struggling with this for several hours now, so after Googling incessantly and finding little to go on, I finally decided to see what kind of help SO might offer me on a piece of my latest CS hw.

Our assignment is to read in and store binary trees, which are given to us in a format like this:
( (root) (left_subtree) (right_subtree))

Each set of matching parens represents a tree, the first thing is the root, the next is the left subtree, and then the right subtree. A subtree doesn't need to be surrounded by parens if it's a leaf, but it can be. To clarify what I mean by that, see the following examples, which are all valid representations of the tree pictured below the code block.

```
(A B C)
(A (B) C)
(A B (C))
((A) (B) (C))
```

[image: a tree]
<sub>(source: [otterbein.edu](http://faculty.otterbein.edu/psanderson/csc205/notes/binaryTreeABC.jpg))</sub>

For a more complex example that illustrates the recursive nature of the definition a bit better, one possible string for the following tree would be:

```
(F(B A (D C E)) (G () (I (H))))
```

Note that, in the right subtree of F [i.e. "(G () (I (H)))"], the "()" is necessary after G to denote the empty left child - but also note that the right subtree of G ["(I (H))"] could also have been represented more simply as "(I H)".

[image: a bigger tree]

I have a binary tree class (and matching TreeNode class) completed except for the essential function to build the tree from this input, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how exactly to parse the string. I have a general idea of how to do it - at least, how the recursion works - but how exactly to go about breaking down the problem into smaller parts is going over my head.

```
//pseudocode musings
TreeNode* Tree::buildFromString(string s){
TreeNode* temp = NULL
if ( the string doesn't represent an empty tree )
  temp = new TreeNode
  temp->data = part of s representing root
  temp->leftChild = buildFromString( part of s representing left subtree)
  temp->rightChild = same as above, but with right subtree     
}
return temp;
```

I'm not having trouble with the recursion per se -- it makes sense, it's not that hard to trace it roughly in your head. The base case works - you kick out of the recursion and head back up the calls once you reach a leaf node, linking the subtrees as you go back.

But I can't figure out how to break the problem down into smaller pieces in the code, which is obviously the whole point of recursion. I want to create substrings of the original to pass to the recursive calls, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the appropriate pieces.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, what is missing is:

- If the string starts with '(', it starts a tree, following 'A' is the root
- If it is, e.g., 'B', that is a leaf
- If it is '(', recurse
- If next is ')', close off the node started above

Comment: This makes perfect sense in English and is pretty much what I was thinking as well, but I just can't seem to figure out how to make it happen in the code. I'm frustrated here - I feel like I'm inches away from the solution, but there's just some piece of the puzzle I'm missing - how can I get the substrings out of the original to pass down to the recursive call?